# Porting OCaml compiler to iOS with a Swift Package

Tags: ios, c, swift, ocaml

I'm currently trying to create a Swift Package (or Cocoa Touch Framework or anything that can be imported into an Xcode Swift Project) to wrap the OCaml compiler into an iOS app.

My goal is to allow an iOS app to dynamically build and run OCaml code from the device. (without requiring an external server or whatever else to build and run the code, but do it directly on the device)

Here are resources I used to document myself and find a solution:

- The OCaml compiler itself (written in C): https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml
- How to Integrate a C Library into an iOS App Written in Swift: https://medium.com/@distillerytech/how-to-integrate-a-c-library-into-an-ios-app-written-in-swift-ef92c0e0d42b
- Trying to understand how the port was done for python for ios: https://github.com/holzschu/python3_ios and https://github.com/holzschu/cpython
- Compiler from OCaml to Javascript: https://github.com/ocsigen/js_of_ocaml
- The Xcode project I tried to setup using the tutorial above (2° dash) wrapping the OCaml compiler with a git submodule (see `.gitmodules` file): https://github.com/NathanFallet/OCamlKit

But I'm unable to compile the package I tried to setup to achieve this goal.

Help is welcomed to realize this huge project

Comment: libsignal builds use CMake, and it looks like OCaml just uses Make. That may mean you integrate it into XCode differently. But, my advice, before you try to work with it in XCode? Cross-compile it for iOS with `make` from Terminal and see if that much can even work. For that, look into the OCaml `configure` file and find the options to set the arm64 target and host, and to disable building the native compiler. (According to your GitHub link README, the native compiler isn't supported for iOS. But the bytecode one might work.)

Comment: Won't generating code from the OCaml compiler violate the Developer Agreement for the Apple AppStore?  Perhaps you are intending a method of distribution other than Apple AppStore for iOS devices.